# How to remove specific pattern from the beginning of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

My problem is that I have a string in javascript and the string may or may not begin with
`(d)` this pattern. Where d is a random number.

What I am looking for is an efficient way to remove the this pattern from the beginning of my string.

For eg:

(3)Abcd should be converted to Abcd,
(412)abc should be converted to abc,
abcd should remain abcd

A normal substring won't do the trick for me, since I don't know the exact number of digits.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = str.replace(/^\(\d+\)/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
str = str.replace(/^\(\d+\)/, "");
```

This will match your pattern (string beginning, opening bracket, one or more digits, closing bracket) and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) it with the empty string if found.